# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

All of the sudden, I started getting quite a few crash reports claiming that the android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity method doesn't exist.

Anyone knows what could be causing this?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity
    at com.example.notification.NotificationHelper.showNotification(NotificationHelper.java:37)
    at com.example.notification.NotificationHelper.showNotification(NotificationHelper.java:19)
    at com.example.content.sync.userdata.TaskSynchronizer$2.onResultReceived(TaskSynchronizer.java:142)
    at com.example.content.sync.BulkRequest.onResultReceived(BulkRequest.java:172)
    at com.example.content.sync.SyncAdapterHelper.pushOrPull(SyncAdapterHelper.java:201)
    at com.example.content.sync.SyncAdapterHelper.syncAll(SyncAdapterHelper.java:60)
    at com.example.content.sync.SyncAdapter.onPerformSync(SyncAdapter.java:139)
    at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:247)
```

Below is my `NotificationHelper` class:

```
public class NotificationHelper {

    public static void showNotification( Context context, String title, String content, MenuItem itemToStart ) {
        showNotification(context, title, content, itemToStart, null, itemToStart.id );
    }
    public static void showNotification( Context context, String title, String content, MenuItem itemToStart, Bundle extras ) {
        showNotification(context, title, content, itemToStart, extras, itemToStart.id );
    }

    public static void showNotification( Context context, String title, String content, MenuItem itemToStart, Bundle extras, int notificationId ) {
        /*
         * Check if user has disabled notifications
         */
        if ( !ProfileManager.areNotificationsEnabled( context ) ) {
            return;
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        Intent contentIntent = new Intent( context, LauncherActivity.class );
        contentIntent.putExtra( MFMainActivity.EXTRA_START_MENUITEM_ID, itemToStart.id );

        builder.setSmallIcon( R.drawable.ic_stat_notify )
               .setAutoCancel( true )
               .setContentTitle( title )
               .setContentText( content )
               .setContentIntent( PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, contentIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, extras ) );

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
        nm.notify( notificationId, builder.build() );
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** As Tushar pointed out, I had started using the `PendingIntent.getActivity()` method with the `Bundle` argument. This method had first been introduced in API 16, which caused the crashes on all devices with earlier API's.

My solution was to call `contentIntent.replaceExtras( extras )` and pass the extras in the content Intent instead of directly to the `getActivity()` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
getActivity(Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags, Bundle options)
```

was only introduced in Android API 16 (4.1). If you run your app on anything below that, it will throw this exception.

You might want to use the version of `getActivity()` that was introduced with API 1, which has the signature (notice lack of `Bundle`):

```
getActivity(Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags)
```

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)

Comment: Damn, how could I have missed this? :-) I will accept your answer shortly